# In Excel 2007 conditional formatting, how to format an entire row based on the content of a cell of a locked column?

Tags: excel

I want to apply a conditional formatting to the entire sheet.

In particular I want to format a row by the value of its cell in a particular column so that if column F contains "something", the entire row is formatted (e.g. red background).

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all cells and then click Conditional Formatting > New Rule. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". In the rule description type:

```
=$F1="Value to check" (or if it's numeric, =$F1=12345)
```

Click the format button and set the fill to red. Click OK